# Adopting UITextInputTraits in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextinputtraits

I am trying to adopt the `UITextInputTraits` for a custom `UIButton` subclass in Swift 3.

I added all the properties specified in the ["Symbols" section of the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinputtraits):

```
import UIKit 

class TextInputButton: UIButton {
    var autocapitalizationType: UITextAutocapitalizationType = .none
    var autocorrectionType: UITextAutocorrectionType         = .no
    var spellCheckingType: UITextSpellCheckingType           = .no
    var enablesReturnKeyAutomatically: Bool                  = false
    var keyboardAppearance: UIKeyboardAppearance             = .default
    var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType                         = .default
    var returnKeyType: UIReturnKeyType                       = .default
    var isSecureTextEntry: Bool                              = false

    // (...rest of class implementation omitted...)
```

However, when I try to compile, `isSecureTextEntry` causes the following error:

> Objective-C method 'setIsSecureTextEntry:' provided by setter for
>   'isSecureTextEntry' does not match the requirement's selector
>   ('setSecureTextEntry:')

If I use the suggested 'fix-it', the property declaration turns into:

```
var @objc(setSecureTextEntry:) isSecureTextEntry: Bool = false
```

...but now I get the three errors:

1. Expected Pattern
2. Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

(wants me to insert a semicolon between `var` and `@objc`),

and:

3. Expected Declaration

What is the correct way of implementing this one property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe not exactly your case, but such adoption of UITextInputTraits worked fine for me

*(minor hint: UIKeyInput extends UITextInputTraits)*

```
public class ShortPasswordEntry : UIControl, UIKeyInput
{
    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    extension ShortPasswordEntry
    {
        public var keyboardType: UIKeyboardType {
            get {
                return .numberPad
            }
            set {
                assertionFailure()
            }
        }
    }
}
```